# Patch panel to patch panel

Tags: networking

I’m in the process of building a cottage/office in our backyard and will be running CAT6 cable there for connectivity. I prefer to keep my cable modem and router in the house so I was thinking of having a patch panel in the house that the long run will be connected to and then terminate in the new cottage with another patch panel (from there it will go to a switch). So it will basically look like:

```
Cable Modem —> Router —> Patch Panel —> (75 ft run) —> Patch Panel —> Switch
```

Is it okay to go directly from patch panel to patch panel? I’m not a networking guy so I’m not sure if this is to spec or not. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's perfectly fine, and actually the preferred way. You usually have a device which connects with a patch cable to a patch panel, which is connected to another panel, which has another patch cable connecting another device.

The patch panel jacks and the cable between them is what's called the **permanent link**, which is usually what's get tested then a new cable installation get's certified. If you also include the patch cables at both ends, it's called the **channel**, which you usually don't bother testing except when fault finding or in some datacenter applications.

Main difference is that the cable used for the permanent link is usually solid core wires, while patch cables commonly use stranded wire. Signal quality they are quite similar, but if you try to terminate cable intended for patch cables in a jack, or you try to fit solid core installation cable into a 8P8C connector you might run into problems due to the difference in diameter of the individual conductors.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it okay to go directly from patch panel to patch panel?

Yes, it's perfectly fine.